# Why is javaScript only working after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to figure out why this code is only working after the second page refresh.

```
var arr = $.makeArray()
$('#content-height div').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).outerHeight());
});

$('#content-height .excerpt').css('height', Math.max.apply( Math, arr ));
```

inside #content-height are two divs that are populated by dynamic content so the height of the divs inside vary..

So i retrieved the height of both contents inside the #content-height and then used it to include a style in one of the two divs so that the height of the content-height would be for both inside the divs..

The thing is that it doesn't find the height at the first page load.. but as soon as I refresh the page once again it corrects everything, so I'm not sure why that is..

Question: Why is it that the javascript code above is only loading after the refreshing the loaded page? (load url first -> does not get full height, refresh page -> gets height of the biggest div and applies it to the smallest)

```
<div id="content-height" class="entry-content kd-recipe-content">
    <div class="excerpt">

    {{ article.excerpt }}

    <div class="content">{{ article.content }}</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It smells like a timing issue. Are you sure that your dynamic content is loaded before you try to get its size? Cache could speed up your loading the second time around, and get it in in time.

Comment: need to show where relationship is between this code and the code that loads the content

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I'm not sure how to make the page load first before the script runs.. is there a way for that? I do have to clear the cache every time I want to test it though to see the error.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: You can check by wrapping everything in a `setTimeout(function() { //here` and seeing if it works